# How do I create a JavaFX BorderPane with no center?

Tags: java, css, javafx, borderpane

I would like to create a BorderPane layout in JavaFX with no center pane.

The code I have written so far only implements the left and right borders and is below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUI_Practice extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String blackBorder = "-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-color: black";

        /* Left column */
        Button save = new Button("Save");
        Button del = new Button("Delete");
        HBox settings = new HBox(save, del);
        VBox leftCol = new VBox(settings);
        leftCol.setStyle(blackBorder);

        /* Right column */
        Button calculate = new Button("Calculate");
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        HBox runButtons = new HBox(calculate, cancel);
        VBox rightCol = new VBox(runButtons);
        rightCol.setStyle(blackBorder);

        /* Set up borderpane */
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        root.setLeft(leftCol);
        root.setRight(rightCol);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

The output it gives is shown in the image below:

[image]

However, I want it to look more like this:

[image]

Where the left and right columns are equal width and take up the entire width of the window. Additionally, the columns do not change width with the window, so the whitespace in the middle gets bigger as the window gets bigger.

What do I need to change to make the columns fill the width of the window?

(P.S. I'm still learning, so if the solution could avoid FXML (which I don't understand yet), that'd be great)

**EDIT:** as per @k88's suggestion, my start method now looks like so:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String blackBorder = "-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-color: black";

        Button calculate = new Button("Calculate");
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        HBox runButtons = new HBox(calculate, cancel);
        VBox rightCol = new VBox(runButtons);
        rightCol.setStyle(blackBorder);

        Button save = new Button("Save");
        Button del= new Button("Delete");
        HBox settings = new HBox(save, load);
        VBox leftCol = new VBox(settings);
        leftCol.setStyle(blackBorder);

        HBox root = new HBox(leftCol, rightCol);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(15));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Giving a window looking like:

[image]

Comment: Can't you put it in a HBox instead ? And then add a BorderPane or whatever you want in each of the nodes of HBox ? Basically replace the BorderPane with an HBox as I don't think the BorderPane has any use here.

Comment: @k88 90% of the beginners use `BorderPane` without know why they are using it. I think it's because it's the default `Pane` (can't remember now) in a fresh install.

Comment: @k88 Thanks for the suggestion, but when I do that, it looks just like the screenshot in my question but with the right column touching the left column and with the whitespace to the right of both of them.

Comment: @JolonB if you want space inbetween the columns you can use the `setSpacing()` property found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#spacingProperty). You can also play around with the `padding` property of each node, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#paddingProperty)

Comment: This is because you have defined a fixed size for your `Scene`, but your content doesn't require this much space - so the space has to go to somewhere. `BorderPane` allocates it to the "center" node, which was empty anyway, while `HBox` allocated it to the right.

Comment: @Jai In theory, I want it to be possible for the scene to be any size (provided it's not too small for the content) so I would like the VBoxes to expand to fit the window, and the buttons to expand to fit the HBoxes they are in.

Comment: @k88 I'm not so fussed about the spacing between the columns. I just want to get rid of the large amount of whitespace in the window by making the VBoxes fill the entire window.

Comment: @JolonB The best you could do is to allocate the extra space equally at the left and right. You could try `HBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)` for this.

Comment: @Jai I know but I kind of want to eliminate the extra space entirely and have the VBoxes (leftCol and rightCol) having a width of 50% of the window, and the buttons to have a width of 50% of the HBoxes they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to get this problem fixed.

1. If you want to still gain the benefits from `BorderPane` (like to have top and bottom panes), you can set a `HBox`/`GridPane` as the center (without setting left/right).
2. If you are not bothered about top and bottom layout implementations, then as @k88 suggested, you can use directly `HBox` or `GridPane` as your root node.

Using `HBox`:

```
HBox.setHGrow(leftCol,Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox.setHGrow(rightCol,Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox root = new HBox();
root.setPadding(new Insets(15));
root.getChildren().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);
```

Using `GridPane`:

```
GridPane root = new GridPane();
ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
col1.setPercentWidth(50);
ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
col2.setPercentWidth(50);
root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2);
root.addRow(0, leftCol,rightCol);
```

**Update:** In either cases, if you want your buttons to auto stretch, bind the width of the buttons to its layout. This way you can control the buttons width proportion in the `HBox`.

```
Button calculate = new Button("Calculate");
Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
HBox runButtons = new HBox(calculate, cancel);
calculate.prefWidthProperty().bind(runButtons.widthProperty().divide(2));
cancel.prefWidthProperty().bind(runButtons.widthProperty().divide(2));
```

**Update 2**: Please find below a sample demo.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sample extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String blackBorder = "-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-color: black";

        Button calculate = new Button("Calculate");
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        HBox runButtons = new HBox(calculate, cancel);
        calculate.prefWidthProperty().bind(runButtons.widthProperty().divide(2));
        cancel.prefWidthProperty().bind(runButtons.widthProperty().divide(2));
        VBox rightCol = new VBox(runButtons);
        rightCol.setStyle(blackBorder);

        Button save = new Button("Save");
        Button del = new Button("Delete");
        HBox settings = new HBox(save, del);
        save.prefWidthProperty().bind(settings.widthProperty().divide(3)); // 1/3
        del.prefWidthProperty().bind(settings.widthProperty().divide(3).multiply(2)); // 2/3
        VBox leftCol = new VBox(settings);
        leftCol.setStyle(blackBorder);


        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col1.setPercentWidth(50);
        ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col2.setPercentWidth(50);
        root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2);
        root.addRow(0, leftCol,rightCol);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String... a) {
        Application.launch(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've used the GridPane implementation, but when I try to make the buttons auto stretch using setHgrow it doesn't change anything. The buttons remain the same size as they were initially. **Edit:** it's the same case when I use the HBox.

Comment: @JolonB and what if you try suggestion 1 ? Use a BorderPane with a HBox as its center. Leave the left and right open. That might fill it out as how you want it.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I've gone and done:  


`save.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
 del.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
 calculate.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
 cancel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);`   


which has made the buttons fill the width of the HBox. Is this the typical way to doing it and would it be considered ugly code, or would this be usual in this situation?

Comment: Also is there any way to set the VBoxes (in suggestion 2) to a widths other than 50%, say left: 70%, right 30%, or would it be better to use the GridPane?

Comment: I would say setting maxWidth is one of the acceptable approach. Or alternately you can bind the buttons width to its layout (updated my answer). In this way, you will NOT set hgrow to each buttons, and you have control over there widths proportion.

Comment: I tried setting the prefWidthProperty of the buttons, and it did cause them to have equal widths (which is great!). But when I did it for all the buttons (using settings.widthProperty() for save/load) the save and load buttons were bigger than the calculate and cancel. I went and set leftCol and rightCol to half the width of the root and that worked perfectly. I'll probably look into GridPane a bit anyway as it seems like the proper way to go. Thanks

Comment: **Edit:** I went and set leftCol and rightCol to half the width of the root and that seemed to have worked, however if I try to set the divide property to something other than 2, say 3 for one and 3/2 for the other it doesn't work and the `settings` is always has an equal or greater width than `runButtons`.

Comment: I assume you are doing the binding wrongly. Updated my answer with the demo code.

Comment: Thanks so much. My code was the same except I still had   `HBox.setHgrow(leftCol, Priority.ALWAYS);
  HBox.setHgrow(rightCol, Priority.ALWAYS);` in it, so I guess that stops it from working (not sure why though). As far as I can tell, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Just a note: it is setHgrow(...), not setHGrow(...).